# Ruby on Rails nested forms on different views

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, web-services

So basically i'm making a google's form like app, the basic structure consists of a user that can create a form once is logged in, each form has multiple questions, and each question has multiple answers.

So what i'm doing is that when a form is created, it makes you also create the questions that that form is going to contain (that part is already implemented), and then, since the show view of each form is going to be public (so you don't have to register in order to answer a form) i want it to contain a form for the answers model, containing a field for each of the answers of each of the questions.

this is what i have done so far.

ROUTES

```
 devise_for :users
  root 'forms#index'
  resources :forms
  post 'forms/new'
```

FORM MODEL

```
class Form < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :questions, dependent: :destroy
    belongs_to :user
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :questions, :reject_if => lambda { |a| a[:body].blank? }
end
```

QUESTION MODEL

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :form
  has_many :answers
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :answers, :allow_destroy => true, :reject_if => lambda { |a| a[:body].blank? }
end
```

ANSWER MODEL

```
class Answer < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :question
end
```

SINCE I'M USING NESTED ATTRIBUTES, I'M MANAGING ALL FROM THE FORM CONTROLLER

```
class FormsController < ApplicationController
    before_action :authenticate_user!, only: [:index]


    def index
        @forms = Form.all
    end

    def new
        numberOfQuestions = 0
        if  params[:numberOfQuestions]
            numberOfQuestions = params[:numberOfQuestions].to_i
        end
        @form = Form.new
        numberOfQuestions.times { @form.questions.build }
    end


    def create
        @form = Form.new(form_params)
        @form.user = current_user
        if @form.save
            redirect_to root_path, notice: "Form correctly created"
        else
            render :new, notice: "Form submition failled"
        end
    end

    def show

        @form = Form.find(params[:id])
        questionsId = @form.questions.collect(&:id)
        numberOfAnswers = questionsId.size

        (0..numberOfAnswers-1).each do |i|
            question = Question.find(questionsId[i])
            question.answers.build
        end
    end

    def destroy
        @form = Form.find(params[:id]).destroy
        redirect_to root_path
    end

    private
        def form_params
            params.require(:form).permit(:title, :user_id, questions_attributes: [ :body, :id, :form_id, answers_attributes: [ :body, :id, :question_id]] )
        end
end
```

AND THIS IS THE VIEW WHERE I WANT TO DISPLAY THE FORM FOR ANSWERING  EACH QUESTION OF THE FORM, BUT WHERE I'M HAVING TROUBLE.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <h1><%= @form.title %></h1>
            <ol>
                <% @form.questions.each do |question| %>
                    <li><%= question.body %></li>
                <% end %>
            </ol>

            <%= form_for @form do |f| %>

                <%= f.fields_for :questions do |builder| %>
                    <% builder.fields_for :answers do |ansBuilder| %>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <%= ansBuilder.text_field :body, class: "form-control", placeholder: "Answer the question" %>
                        </div>
                    <% end %>
                <% end %>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <%= f.submit class: "btn btn-primary", value: "Send Answer" %>
                </div>
            <% end %>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

At the point where my code is, i was expecting it to show a field for each of the questions of the corresponding form at the show path for each form (for example at ./forms/1), but it simply does not display the form for the Answer model.

this is the link of the repo, in case you want to check out something else: https://github.com/sebasdeldi/Formularia

Thanks a lot for reading.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to build empty `answer` objects in your `new` action for it to show up in your form.  Something like this:

```
def new
    numberOfQuestions = 0
    if  params[:numberOfQuestions]
        numberOfQuestions = params[:numberOfQuestions].to_i
    end
    @form = Form.new
    numberOfQuestions.times  do
       question = @form.questions.build
       3.times {question.answers.build}
    end
end
```

For nested attributes, the controller has to build one or more empty children, or in this case, grandchildren, for the fields to show in the form.  See the [9.2 Nested Forms](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html) section of the Rails guide for some documentation and example about this.

Comment: thanks for helping, but nothing happened with the change that you suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Hello Sebastian Delgado,

I seen your code and the problem is on the:
```

```

You are trying to access properties that does not exists.

Only you should take the first `field_for` like this:

```

```
            <% end %>

            <div class="form-group">
                <%= f.submit class: "btn btn-primary", value: "Send Answer" %>
            </div>
        <% end %>
```

```

With this you will get the answers to each questions, and on the controller you should manage the data before save it.

Try it and let me know.